# textEmailAddress|textAutoComplete not working on lots of devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-inputtype, android-textinputedittext

I can tell that the devices are capable of displaying suggestions, as I can see them in Google apps, like Messaging, Gmail etc., etc.

I can't get them to work in my own fields however, but it does work on our Samsung device (I suspect that Samsung do more than the vanilla keyboard).

Here is an example of one of the fields:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_email_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textAutoComplete" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

if I only use textAutoComplete, I can see the bar/boxes where suggestions would appear, but they are empty! And of course, not using textEmailAddress means a less convenient typing experience.

dependencies involved are:

```
     compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
```

This is a simple thing to do, so I feel like I'm doing something wrong, any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm seeing the same thing right now.

Comment: Sorry @HondaGuy, nope - it seems to vary per device. It could be based on what keyboard is installed or anything else that conflicts. 
I downloaded a demo application with all types of IMM and was able to see that it gave different results on different devices. 
Perhaps by now it is fixed, but I haven't been paying attention to this - the only textboxes we actually use are in the registration and login screens